# How to fetch last added or edited records from SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, migration, db2

Currently I'm working on database migration, for this I'm using Pentaho Kettle and Perl scripts.
The migration is from Tumor-registry SQL Server database to CIDER IBM DB2 database.

In this task I want to achieve two objective.

1. Initial migration: in this I'm migrating all the rows (e.g. 100000) from Tumor-registry (SQL Server) to CIDER (IBM DB2).
2. Subsequent migration: the Tumor-registry SQL Server database is constantly updating on and off.
   It's constantly adding new rows or edits already existing rows.

I have figured out the first step but facing two problems in second step.

a) If Tumor-registry SQL Server database is updated with for example new 10 rows; how can I get those new 10 rows?

b) If already existing 10 rows are updated then how can I get those 10 rows and also want to know which columns are updated.

My Tumor-registry database contain approximately 50 tables.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would investigate the [SQL Server replication features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx) - that kind of functionality is already built and ready to use - you just need to configure it appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new column with [**TIMESTAMP**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260631%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) datatype.This will keep track of the latest edited records in the table.

OR

You can use [**CHECKSUM**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189788.aspx) function in Sql server.

Comment: The problem is I can not change the schema.

Answer (score 0):

i think that will provide u a solution by using triger

create triger trigername on tablename 
after insert 
as
declare @variablename_1 datatype;
select @variablename_1 = column_name from inserted ;

if you want save data in anohter table that last inserted then create an other table

insert into tablename values (@variablename_1);

Answer (score 0):

You could use IBM Change Data Capture, it will take all the DDL and DML in the source database, and replicate them appropiately in the target database.

http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/infosphere/change-data-capture/

It seems that there are other solutions from other vendors, take a look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_data_capture